# ResponsiveVoice.js sometimes speak on Indonesian Female voice when i use Indonesian male voice

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, responsivevoice

Hello i successfully implementing 'Indonesian Male' Text-To-Speech using ResponsiveVoice.js but sometimes it's returning 'Female Voice', why that happen ?

here is my code

```
var paramSpeak = {
    onstart: onStartSpeak,
    onend: onEndSpeak,
    pitch: 1
}

function setResponse(val) { 
    paramSpeak.onstart(val);
    responsiveVoice.speak(val,"Indonesian Male",paramSpeak);
}
```

Comment: It seems like there's an issue on their end with caching, or something similar. When switching between genders, the voices don't change. Even switching to another language the gender becomes stuck: you probably have to file a bug report of sorts with their API.

Comment: @HumbaLumbaOrcestra I suggest you to store the voice gender value in a variable like so: 
var maleVoice = 'Male'';
responsiveVoice.speak(vall, 'Indonesian ' + maleVoice, paramSpeak);

Let me know if it works other I will create jsfiddle and try again with you.